# VM instance google cloud nuget dependency error when using Docker-compose

Tags: docker, .net-core, google-cloud-platform, docker-compose, nuget

So I'm doing a project where I use a sql-server container and my own container with my api. I user docker-compose to run those at the same time and specify the ports etc. This works fine on my local machine and on the local machines of my team mates. This also works on VM's that we run on our local machine.

But now when trying to deploy our api to google-cloud we run in several errors. We think that the easiest way to deploy is on a VM instance and user docker-compose build and docker-compose run. Docker-compose workss but we get the error down below.

```
System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed'. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (0x80131040)
File name: 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed'
```

In our .csproj file the version is declared as 3.0.0 and when we change it to 12.0.0 or 12.0.0.0 the docker-compose build won't even run. So docker-compose works.

Any ideas on what the problem is? Keep in mind I'm still a newbie in deploying to google.

Comment: I've got this issue when trying to publish to Azure. But the version that can't be found for me is `9.0.0.0` even though I'm using `12.0.0.0`.

Comment: @FrancisDucharme I am not able to use Azure because my subscription doesn't include the containers.